# Freehand editing in QGIS

Tags: editing, digitizing

Is there a way to cut polygons in QGIS using freehand tool? Unfortunately Freehand Editing tool in QGIS 2.x does not provide such functionality. There is a tool for cutting polygons with standard editing mode [image]. But I need to cut polygons with freehand mode.Is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "freehand mode" - the polygon cut tool allows you to use an arbitrary line and to add and subtract nodes to it later

Comment: I mean not to click every time mouse button for polygon verices but draw polygon with freehand digitizing like it ia available in Freehand Editing tool

Comment: One option may be to digitise your split lines into a scratch layer using the freehand editing tool and then use that as an input for the Split With Lines processing tool.

Comment: I think Sergey is referring to stream digitizing ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, i'd like to have tool providing stream digitizing when cutting polygons

Comment: See BeePen plugin for QGIS3 https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/beePen/